# I'm looking for an advice how to crate an intuitive web UI for linear regression model

Tags: user-communication, mental-models, intuitive

Persona: non-technical user who defines several examples of their work and resulting prices. She is a crochet artist who can give several items with their properties. (e.g: 8cm high bear, crochet loop is 0.5 mm, thread silk, = $35, etc). Now the application provides design templates and the end-user can even generate/create their own designs resulting in design parameters.
The pricing page's goal is to provide the most accurate price for the custom design.
The artist has UI with a list of pricing examples (a crochet toy and a price) and the regression model will generate a price for an arbitrary design.
The challenge is how to communicate errors. For example, if the artist provides two examples with identical size, and loop size but the second one uses a more expensive (as per prior examples) thread although the final price is lower.
The hypothetical UI could be something like this list:
[image]

The table above shows the predicted pricing error for a chicken toy. One thing I was considering, was adding increase/decrease buttons around the example price to adjust the prediction. The trouble is that if I start increasing the price of the chicken toy from $25 to $40, the whole model updates as well and the artist will see other predictions change slightly. Also, it is perfectly possible that the price of the chicken $25 is perfectly valid but the other ones are too expensive.

I'm aware the example provided is a bit convoluted but I can't come up with a better description of the problem.

What I'm after is suggestions of simpler UI/UX for the artist to adjust the prices, so she understands why some prices are predicted incorrectly without introducing her to the linear regression (although the regression in my app is linear the parameters are modified with non-linear functions, this way the model predicts well the discounted prices for increased sizes e.g. 3 times bigger toy can be perfectly modeled to be only 2.2 times more expensive, etc.) Ideally, the UI will not need to leak the details of the math behind the pricing modeling and be rather something that seems to work well and provide trust in correct pricing prediction.

Comment: If I understand you right, you're saying that changing the chicken price (e.g. to match the predicted price) would affect the rest because the price column is itself a factor in your prediction formula? That seems like a very hard problem to fix, like a Jenga tower where the user has to adjust one piece so it sits right, but the balance of every other piece is lost. Maybe your formula can exclude that and use a constant or constants to determine the base number for the price, or a premade dataset plus some global coefficient set by the user, or something.

Comment: As for the UI/UX, I think a nice approach might be a range slider [like this](https://i.imgur.com/m8eSMpA.png) showing a minimum and maximum suggested price, and then add a pin for where they're set their price; they can then see whether they're below, within, or above the expected range.

Comment: better widgets representing what I'm doing currently are nice but they are just a sugar coating. I'm looking forward to a more fundamental change in general.

Comment: The first thought that comes to mind is, display the Prices and Predicted Prices on a chart. Let the crochet artist move the current work piece's price around and update the other prices with each move. Also keep an indicator where the moved price started out.

Answer (score 0):

The assumption that the cost of a product scales linearly is probably not taking into consideration certain factors like how long it takes to make the product (regardless of the cost of materials), but let's say you just want to simplify things and help the user with pricing, then I think that a visual display of the model on a chart or graph is the easiest way to go. After all, that's the basis of linear regression calculation. Also, as they enter in more items, then can see the change in the pricing model being calculated. There are already plenty of components that allow you to work with various elements on a graph to make it dynamic and interactive (e.g. think of the mortgage calculators on bank websites).

If you want to stick with the table only, I would suggest that you put the actual price that the user wants to set the product at after the predicted price, because it doesn't matter what the predicted price is as long as it is still clear to the user what the actual price of the product is. That way, they can take into consideration what the calculated value is and put in the value they think is most appropriate. I would also consider what variables you want the user to be able to change, and what they shouldn't tinker with, and make it more obvious in the interface that you are going to create.